# Async-reading databases in node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, q

I am trying to read data from a local database and then use this data in my node.js server. I am using the mssql package for the queries.

However, since mssql reads data asynchronously, I want to make sure that the data is ready before running the server. I tried to create promises as follows, with the Q package:

```
# v is the variable to populate with data
callSql = (v,db,table) ->
    d = Q.defer()

    sql.connect cfg, (err) ->

    request = new sql.Request()
    request.query "select * from " + table, (err, data) ->
        data.forEach (row) ->
            v.push row
        console.log "Read "+ table
        d.resolve data

    d.promise
```

I then try to read data from several tables and proceed to run the server as it is done:

```
callSql var1, con1, table1
.then callSql var2, con2, table2
.then callSql var3, con1, table3
.then ->  console.log 'start server' #etc
```

I expected to get data from table1, then from table2 and so on. However, the log shows that tables are not read in order, so my server sometimes starts without having all data ready.

I also tried with JQDeferred with similar results. What am I doing wrong? How can I force node to read the tables in sequence and only then run the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is running them synchronously, in a chained fashion.  Put the asynch ones in an array, and the "spread" the results. I am not a coffee script guy, but collect your promises in an array

```
var promises =[
   callSql(var1, con1, table1)
   , callSql(var2, con2, table2)
   , callSql(var3, con3, table3)
]

Q.all(promises).spread(function(results1, results2 results3){
 console.log 'start server' 
})
```

Edit: missed the q.all

Comment: That does the trick, thanks. Yet I still don't grasp why I was running them in sequence, as you say, but get the results in random order.

Comment: dont know enough about coffee script to help you there,

Comment: I don't think it has to do with cs vs js, after all cs gets translated to js in quite a straightforward manner. Still, thanks.

Comment: essentially you are calling a promise chain which each piece needs to complete and provide the value prior to the next step in the chain.  This is through the "Then" method - which tells the code to wait  for the function to complete and provide the result THEN move on.  Having each sql statement as chained together via then's means that the former need to complete prior to the latter starting.  Q.all takes an array of promises and waits for them all to complete prior to moving on.